# docker build cache invalidation on subsequent layers even they only add files

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I know about COPY and ADD will invalidate cache if files changed. However I am wondering why all subsequent layers will be regenerated even the content did not change. Lets say I have two COPY instructions, for the first one the files changed and cache invalidates forcing the second COPY to be regenerated also. The second COPY results in the same dir hash but gets a new layer id -> when pushing the image both layers are getting uploaded. Is there a way to only push the layers that really changed (contentwise)? My usecase: each COPY just adds files, no removing or changing (even on meta data).

Answer (score 1):

The images are built on layers that are incremental, in other words the layers stay on on top of the other - each layer is a delta on top of the previous one.

If you change a layer at the base of your docker image build, all the subsequent layers are invalidated.

To minimize this, place the commands that are less likely to alter the layers first.